# Toggle add remove a class

Tags: jquery, class, toggle

Hi I'm learning Jquery.

I want to add and remove the class of "card-open" to the parent div when I click on the the link. On the first click the class is added. But when I click again the class is not removed. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.toggle-box').hide();

$('a.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.toggle-box')
    $('.toggle-box').not(elem).hide();
    elem.toggle('slow');

    var parent_div = $(this).parent().addClass('card-open');
    $('.card').find('div').not(parent_div).removeClass('card-open');
});
});
```

HTML:

```
          <div class="card">


          <h3><a href="">Title</a></h3>
          <h4>date</h4>


          <a href="#" class="togglelink"></a>
          <div class="toggle-box">
            <p>Description</p>
            <p><strong>Employee Count:</strong> 5</p>
          </div>


          <img src="assets/img/open-arrow.svg" alt="Open Event">


      </div>
```

Comment: Just use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Can you provide your HTML markup?

Comment: You can see a good example of `.toggleClass()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Updated with html markup

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix based helpful feedback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.toggle-box').hide();

$('a.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.toggle-box')
    $('.toggle-box').not(elem).hide();
    elem.toggle('slow');

    var parent_div = $(this).parent().toggleClass('card-open');

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your info. Just use toggleClass and target the .parent() div.

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h2K7T/1/

HTML :

```
<div class="card">
    <h3><a href="">Title</a></h3>
    <h4>date</h4>
    <a href="#" class="togglelink">Link</a> <!-- Your link was empty -->
    <div class="toggle-box">
        <p>Description</p>
        <p><strong>Employee Count:</strong> 5</p>
    </div>
    <img src="assets/img/open-arrow.svg" alt="Open Event">
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggle-box').hide(); // This should really just be done with CSS instead. 

    $('a.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').toggleClass('card-open');
    });
});
```

**Note** : If you load jQuery and your scripts at the bottom of the page, you don't need document.ready since your DOM will already be loaded.